# Pull data into filter or new field

Tags: looker-studio

I need to keep updating a filter by adding landing page URLs to it - but those URLs already exist in Google Sheets (and are updated there first).

Is there a way to make the filter pull directly from the sheet?

Thanks,

Steve

Answer (score 1):

How about using the sheet as a halfway house for your main data source, and using formulas to filter the data there before it even reaches GDS?